# How to synchronize HTML5 local/webStorage and server-side storage?

Tags: html, web-applications, storage, offline-mode, firebase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to synchronize local HTML5 DB (WebSQL Storage, SQLite) with a server (2 way sync)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744522/best-way-to-synchronize-local-html5-db-websql-storage-sqlite-with-a-server-2)

I'm currently seeking solutions for transparently and automatically synchronizing and replicating across the client-side HTML5 localStorage or web storage and (maybe multiple) server-side storage(s) (the only requirement here that it should be simple and affordable to install on a regular hosting service).

So do you have any experience with such libraries/technologies that offer data storage which automate the client-server storage synchronization and allow data to be available either offline or online or both? I think this is a fairly common scenario of web applications supporting offline mode...

Comment: The problem of synchronization is very hard with just one server and one client, but if you take into account multiple clients (desktop/mobile) and multiple servers, it becomes that much harder. That said, I'd be very interested to know if you find any libraries, solutions, or just plain basic ideas for doing this. Cheers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Firebase](http://www.firebase.com/how-it-works.html) offers this functionality as a service.
 Another alternative is [Parse](https://parse.com).

Answer (score 5):

It kind of depends on what you want. There is a great tutorial to get you started at http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/01/offline-web-applications/ Unless you want to do something complicated, you should not need that much of a framework to do it for you. I guess you could save a few lines of code on the client using jQuery. You basically want to keep in your store a record of when the last change was made to the store, when the last update was to the server, and use send the localStorage variable encoded as JSON in an XHR (or just the bit of the local store you want to send). Then, on the server, you can decode the JSON and do what you want with it, processing it or just using PHP's serialize to dump it to a database.

If you have something particular in mind, do mention it.

Comment: Thanks for the great article! It demonstrates the principle and the usage of the relevant APIs wonderfully. However, it only shows a manual solution to a very specific subcase. As Anurag said, things quickly get non-trivial when concurrency, two-way synchronization, error handling etc. come in. That's why I'm searching for a more managed way.

Comment: A more detailed article on data synchronization: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-html5db/index.html

Answer (score 2):

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744522/best-way-to-synchronize-local-html5-db-storage-with-a-server) is rather similar.

There, 'quick connect' - http://quickconnect.pbworks.com/Using-Enterprise-Synchronization
and my personal favorit 'persistenceJS' - https://github.com/zefhemel/persistencejs are recommended.

As soon as I gather personal experience, I'll update this post.

Comment: Have you gathered personal experience yet?

Comment: I actually ended up writing my own solution based on backbone.js

Comment: Have you made it opensource? can you share it with us?

Comment: It is not generic. If remote-to-local syncing is what you're after, take a look at backbone.js . If your server exposes its data through a REST API (the 'purer' the better), it will probably do what you need.

Comment: TumbleCow Can you post ur code on git/

Answer (score 1):

I just found a quite new framework which does just that: [Impel.inTouch](http://impel.simulacre.org/api/Impel.inTouch). Its schema definition seems a bit inconvenient, but definitely worth a try.

Comment: Ironically, I found this answer just a bit after offering a bounty. :D

Comment: Unfortunately Impel is no longer being supported - and what currently exists only works with MooTools.