# Are there any drawbacks to using localStorage instead of Cookies?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, local-storage

On my previous websites, I used to use a cookie to display a pre-home page only on the first visit. That worked great ([see for example here](http://newyork.arte.tv/)), but using cookies is not so trendy today, so I want to avoid it as much as possible.

Now, my new website projects almost always have pre-home launched via javascript (showing a modalbox), so I don't need to do any action on the server side. I'm considering to use HTML5 localStorage instead of cookies, with a fallback on cookies if the browser does not have localStorage. Is this a good idea? What is the impact in terms of usability, privacy protection and website performance?

Using localStorage will improve usability for users that have disabled cookies. But I know that some HTML5 features are only opt-in (like geolocalisation) in some browser. Is there any restriction like that for localStorage on any browser ? Is there any case where I will get a JS error if localStorage is available but deactivated for my site ?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

### Usability

The user will not know if you are using localStorage or a cookie. If a user disable cookies, localStorage will not work either.

### Performance

There is no noticeable speed difference between the two methods.

### sessionStorage

sessionStorage is only for that browser tab's session. If you close the tab, the session will be lost and the data will be lost too, it's similar to a session variable on any backend language.

### localStorage

localStorage will be available for any tab or window in the browser, and will exist until it is deleted by the user or the program. Unlike a cookie, you cannot setup expiration. localStorage has a much larger storage limit as well.

### Your Questions

1. You are not using this data server side, so you don't need a cookie. localStorage is never sent to the server unlike a cookie.
2. If the user disables the cookies, localStorage will not work either.

### Fallback Example

You can use a Modernizr to verify if localStorage is available and if not, use store a cookie instead.

```
if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
    // supports HTML5 Storage :D
} else {
    // does not support HTML5 Storage :(
}
```

You can also forego Modernizr and use the check `typeof Storage !== 'undefined'`.

Comment: This answer has more to do with `sessionStorage` versus `localStorage` than anything to do with `cookie`s like the OP wanted

Comment: @just.another.programmer i don't know if you read his question, but he is not asking about cookies, he wrote "I don't need to do any action on the server side" so he doesn't need cookie he need a localStorage or a sessionStorage

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Vinícius Moraes, but how are you so sure that Usability will not be impacted ? LocalStorage and cookies are not the same. For example a user that has disabled cookies would see a difference if I use localStorage, which impove the usability. I know that some HTML5 features are only opt-in (like geolocalisation) in some browser. Is there any restriction like that for localStorage on any browser ?

Comment: To detect localStorage support (in order to provide a fallback solution), I simply use `if(window.localStorage)`.

Comment: @FabienQuatravaux the user will not see any difference because if you disabled the cookies, `cookies` will not work and `localStorage` don't either. There is not restriction `opt-in` for localStorage

Comment: You are right ! In Chrome at least, disabling cookies will also disable localStorage. And I was wrong because if "cookies" are disabled, accessing `window.localStorage` would throw an exception whereas using `Modernizr.localstorage` will just return false. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Exactly :D and thanks for the tip about what i wrote `drawback` instead of `fallback`

Answer (score 35):

Comparing LS vs cookies is comparing apples to oranges.

Cookies and LS are completely different things for different purposes. LS is a tool that allows your *client* (javascript code) to store its data locally, without transmitting it to the server. Cookies is a tool for the *client-server communication*. The whole point of cookies is to be sent over with each request.

In the past cookies were often abused to emulate the local storage, just because it was the only possibility for a javascript application to write anything to the client's hard drive. But generally LS is not a replacement for cookies, so if you need something that both client and server should read and write, use cookies, not LS.

Comment: I don't want to compare LocalStorage and cookies _in general_, which is silly, but only in the case I described here. As I said, I do not need to have something that needs to be sent back on the server, so both cookies and LocalStorage are OK. But which one is the best ?

Comment: @FabienQuatravaux: if you don't need to do anything server-side, then LS is fine.

Comment: Funny, and now there will probably be abuse the other way around with local storage...

Comment: This makes more sense to me.

Comment: LS are more comparable to session variables; a way to save data across pages (or settings or preferences for a user) without storing in a DB.

Answer (score 8):

One point to add, unlike cookie normally shared cross protocol, the storages stick to same-origin policy. As a consequence sites share the same domain but hosted on different protocol do not share the stored data.

Say if your website need to work across http and https. For example, when user clicked the "purchase link" they will land on https secured checkout, then the checkout won't be able to retrieve the data previously stored on http site, even when they share the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

[It doesn't look easy for the server to read the localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631087/how-to-synchronize-html5-local-webstorage-and-server-side-storage). That may come in handy though, knowing your data is all client-side, making it safe from sniffing.

Cookies can't be written over, only added to and read:

```
alert(document.cookie);
document.cookie = "nope";
alert(document.cookie);
```

Comment: -1 you can use sessionStorage, so there is no sniffing like you said.

Comment: cookies *can* be written. 
`alert(document.cookie);
document.cookie = "test=nope";
alert(document.cookie);
document.cookie = "test=yep";
alert(document.cookie);`

Comment: Yea, but `written over`, like, the original stuff still stays

Answer (score 0):

The one thing I didn't like about using 'localstorage' is that all your script code is visible when you 'inspect' (F12) the page. Go into **SOURCES** and from the left panel locate your website name and open it. All your code within the  tags is totally visible. So if you've got some sensitive values on display, liked hashed passwords, special words, they all there for the world to see. I'm not sure what the world will do with this info, but it's not very secure.

Comment: Localstorage and cookies do not differ on this point : you can both read them using the inspector. And yes, sure, do not store sensitive data on the front side if you don't want to disclose them.