# How to synch SQLite data to server in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I'm a total noob when it comes to iPhone development and have been tasked to create a database app that can download and upload sqlite data to and from a server via http using web services. So far I already have a form for retrieving and saving data to a SQLite database and now I need some information on how I can upload the SQLite data to a server. The SQLite database will only have one table with 3 columns and about 200 rows max. I hope somebody can point me to the right direction or lead me to some sample codes.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You can also check this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744522/best-way-to-synchronize-local-html5-db-websql-storage-sqlite-with-a-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using HTTP to get data into the iPhone, you should also use HTTP to get data out of the iPhone. That way, you can query the SQLITE database and send the data through HTTP to a remote server.

It's pretty simple to accomplish since you have all the HTTP protocol implemented in the SDK.

On the server side, you can use whatever you want: Apache+PHP, Tomcat, JBoss, ASP.NET, you name it.