# Local database as fallback/offline database in webapp

Tags: sql, html, web-applications, offline

I have a webapp for iPad (its only for iPad) that uses a MySQL database and PHP to handle the data. The app is only using SELECT, no INSERT og UPDATE to the database.

But you are required to be online for the app to work, but I'm considering making the app usable offline aswell. My question is how do I make a MySQL database offline and how do I make the app use the local/offline database if offline and the MySQL database if online?
If the user is online after using it offline the database should update to check if there is any changes in the online database.

Comment: This was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744522/best-way-to-synchronize-local-html5-db-websql-storage-sqlite-with-a-server