# PhoneGap with Sqlite

Tags: cordova, sqlite

I am working with an android application with PhoneGap.

Problem is , I already created a database by sqlite. I want to synchronize with that db.
(Once the database has been created it must be told that it needs to synchronize with a remote service.)

How can I do that?

Comment: This blog entry details on how to do it: http://gauravstomar.blogspot.com/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question, but you can look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744522/best-way-to-synchronize-local-html5-db-websql-storage-sqlite-with-a-server-2/

Answer (score 0):

a blog show how to do it 
[Simple Offline Data Synchronization for Mobile Web and PhoneGap Applications](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/05/simple-offline-data-synchronization-for-mobile-web-and-phonegap-applications/)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) for more info.