# Store Data using HTML, Retrieve using PhoneGap App

Tags: html, sqlite, cordova, local-storage

Say the user browsed to http://mydomain.com?data=data and the HTML stored this URL + data.

Then the user launched a native app built with PhoneGap and the App wants to retrieve http://thedomain.com?data=data that was stored by the HTML5 webpage.

Is there common storage between the Browsed HTML and the Native PhoneGap App so data can be passed from web browsing to Native Mobile Application?

Some ideas and a snippet would help greatly to figure this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

not possible i guess. your app is separate. it wont be able to access the localstorage quota of your website.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'the HTML stored this URL + data' ?
The HTML cannot store itself anything dymamically. It's a language ;) anyway the browser with html5 can do.

You have two options:

a\ local storage
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp

b\ web sql database
http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/

now about synchro:
[Best way to synchronize local HTML5 DB (WebSQL Storage, SQLite) with a server (2 way sync)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744522/best-way-to-synchronize-local-html5-db-websql-storage-sqlite-with-a-server-2)

'Is there common storage between...' <- sure. the same browser and the same domain -> no problem

want more? only  books like that can help you: http://books.google.ie/books/about/The_Web_Application_Hacker_s_Handbook.html?id=_jv97STVvrQC&redir_esc=y