# Web application without a server

Tags: web-applications, offline, data-synchronization

I am a beginner in web development, and now I am in training and I was asked to create a web application, knowing that they do not have a server. is it there's a solution?

Comment: I need to develop a tool to calculate the rating of a service after  entering a several criteria and generate an excel file to send to the client. They require that data must be stored in a central database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your computer as a server (provider of you web application) during the training. If you need to make the app available in long term or for more users, you can always host it in providers like Amazon.

If you need help to configure your pc as a server, please provide more information (what tecnology are you learning? What should the web application do?).

Comment: I need to develop a tool to calculate the rating of a service after  entering a several criteria and generate an excel file to send to the client. They require that data must be stored in a central database. 
At this moment !  I have not yet chosen the technologies with which I will work

Comment: You don't need a web app for that. It can be a desktop application or even console app. Any application can connect to databases through technologies like JDBC (for Java) and ADO.Net (for C#), or using some API provided by the programming language API. If you want it to be a web app, you can develop it in you computer and then transfer it to a server later on. I suggest you to take a look at the popular technologies (Java, C#, Ruby On Rails, Javascript, etc) or ask someone for which technology will help you more in your company or carreer. Good luck.

Comment: @user3396142 does that answer your question?

Comment: I suggested your first answer, and we just agree to make a desktop as a local server, but only if the data is still available even if the server shuts down, and once the server is functional, a set of synchronization of data must be applied. Have you an idea how to do this ?

Comment: when the server (local desktop) is turned on, it must synchronize with what?

Comment: The web application must keep working in offline mode. So ! if the user makes some update in data, it must be synchronized with the central database once the server is turned on.

Comment: I thinks this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744522/best-way-to-synchronize-local-html5-db-websql-storage-sqlite-with-a-server-2?rq=1

Comment: why did you unnacepted my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a JavaScript application using Backbone.js, Angular.js, or [similar](http://todomvc.com/), and just use [jQuery-mockjax](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax) to fake JSON responses from a server.

Additionally, you could also just make a small application in Node.js that is bundled with Express.js, but then, that would be a server.

Answer (score 0):

You would in all cases need a server to host the web application. Otherwise no one will be able to reach it. You can however host it with an external hosting provider.

If it's a training application you can also just host it on your local computer temporarily.

Comment: It's an application that will be deployed at the end of my training        
So please which architecture will you advise me, to implement an independent network application, but that recovers data from a central database ?