# WebSqlSync lib, could it use several keys as 'idName'

Tags: html, web-applications, storage, data-synchronization

I read about a lib named **WebSqlSync** as an answer to this question: [Best way to synchronize local HTML5 DB (WebSQL Storage, SQLite) with a server (2 way sync)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744522/best-way-to-synchronize-local-html5-db-websql-storage-sqlite-with-a-server-2/2313945#2313945)

When reading the documentation I understood that it was only possible to have a single key field to identify the row to sync. As the example given suggests:

```
TABLES_TO_SYNC = [
    {tableName : 'table1', idName : 'the_id'},
    {tableName : 'table2'} //if idName not specified, it will assume that it's "id"
];
```

**I wonders if it would accept several keys to identify the row** if a table uses several fields as component of the key, so it would look like this:

```
{tableName : 'table1', idName : 'id_1,id_2,id_3'},
```

Answer (score 1):

Not possible without modifying the library.

A simpler solution would be to create a computed/virtual column like "ComposedId" composed with the concatenation of the values of the ids (ex. "ComposedId" = "id_1Value+id_2Value+id_3Value").

And then, you would declare the table with only 1 ID : {tableName : 'table1', idName : 'ComposedId'},

Hope this helps